# How can user must close all the active form before exiting the application In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 Form

1. Form Menu
2. Form Login
3. Form Program1
4. Form Program2

I want before closing the application i must close all the active form. Or something like i need to logout first before closing the app is fine too

ps : sorry for my explanation hope someone can help me

To Login I use module

```
Module Module1
#Region "Login"
    Public Sub logins()
        MenuUtama.ProgramAplikasiToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        MenuUtama.ProgramSedehana1ToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        MenuUtama.ProgramSederhana2ToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        MenuUtama.LogoutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        MenuUtama.LoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Logout"
    Public Sub logouts()
        MenuUtama.ProgramAplikasiToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        MenuUtama.ProgramSedehana1ToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        MenuUtama.ProgramSederhana2ToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        MenuUtama.LogoutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        MenuUtama.LoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
    End Sub
#End Region
End Module
```

To Call Login From the module

```
Private Sub validation()
        If txtusername.Text = "" Or txtpassword.Text = "" Then 
            MsgBox("Input Your Username or password", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        ElseIf txtusername.Text = "user" And txtpassword.Text = "password" Then  
            MsgBox("Login Succses", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRight)
            logins()
            Me.Close()
        Else MsgBox("Wrong Password", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        End If
    End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        validation()
    End Sub
```

Code in Form Menu

```
Private Sub close() 

        Dim result As DialogResult = MsgBox("You sure want to close the app?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
        If result = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.Close()
        Else
            Return
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub KeluarToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles KeluarToolStripMenuItem.Click
        close() 
End Sub
```

What i want is, if a Form is active, and i close the application, Then come massage to inform the user that he need to close all the active form first.
For now i use this to inform if user want to exit the application

Comment: You can get the list of open forms looking at _Application.OpenForms_

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: How do you show the forms other than the main form?

Comment: Private Sub ProgramSedehana1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProgramSedehana1ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Form1.MdiParent = Me
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you catch either the Closed or Closing event from Form Menu (Open the Form code, select Form events, then in the next box to the right select either closed or closing)

You'll have a new section of code like this:

Private Sub Form1_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed

End Sub

Then in the middle of that new Sub, you can type something like:

If Login.visible then
msgbox("you need to close the Login form")
End If

Also note that if you make your second, third and fourth windows modal, then the user will HAVE to close them before ending up back at the Main window.